# How to schedule hundreds of thousands of tasks?

Tags: python

We have hundreds of thousands of tasks that need to be run at a variety of arbitrary intervals, some every hour, some every day, and so on. The tasks are resource intensive and need to be distributed across many machines.

Right now tasks are stored in a database with an "execute at this time" timestamp. To find tasks that need to be executed, we query the database for jobs that are due to be executed, then update the timestamps when the task is complete. Naturally this leads to a substantial write load on the database.

As far as I can tell, we are looking for something to release tasks into a queue at a set interval. (Workers could then request tasks from that queue.)

What is the best way to schedule recurring tasks at scale?

For what it's worth we're largely using Python, although we have no problems using components (RabbitMQ?) written in other languages.

**UPDATE:** Right now we have about 350,000 tasks that run every half hour or so, with some variation. 350,000 tasks * 48 times per day is 16,800,000 tasks executed per day.

**UPDATE 2:** There are no dependencies. The tasks do not have to be executed in order and do not rely on previous results.

Comment: Are you using the database for its ACID properties?  For example, if the system crashes, when it comes back up is it important that the database knows exactly when each task last ran?

Comment: How critical a failure is it if something does not run on time? How critical a failure is it if something is run twice?

Comment: "Naturally this leads to a substantial write load on the database."?  Really?  Why?  What's the actual peak load?  You have 86,400 seconds per day; the odds of attempting two concurrent writes are pretty low.  I'd say that unless you had 2.5 million tasks, you're peak write load will will be quite small.  What evidence do you have of this "substantial" write load?  What do you consider "substantial"?

Comment: @Daniel - No, ACID is not particularly important. 

@quillbreaker - It is not critical that jobs run precisely on time. It's also not a problem if they run twice.

@S.Lott - I may have phrased this wrong. When a job is complete the database is updated. This happens several hundred times per second. While it is clearly possible to update a (perhaps sharded) database at that speed, it is resource intensive. Currently we're using Amazon's SimpleDB product - the machine time associated with the writes/indexing is costly.

Comment: @wehriam: The math of "hundreds of thousands of tasks" and "several hundred times per second" isn't multiplying out right.  For you to have several hundred finishing each second, you'd have to run at least 8,640,000 jobs each day.  Since each task would have to take less than 100'th of a second, it's hard to figure out what's real work and what's just overhead at that point.  Please update the question -- do not add comments -- to clarify this scheduling nightmare.

Comment: What about dependencies?  How many of these tasks depend on previous tasks running and/or the dependent task completing with a certain return code?

Comment: I feel like I must be missing something here. You say you're using Amazon SimpleDB, but that's a web service, isn't it? Are you really making hundreds of writes a second to a server somebody else controls? That seems crazy, unless your application is already dependent on Amazon's web services for something else. SimpleDB doesn't even support non-string values, does it?

Comment: @Mark - SimpleDB indexes values, all of which are stored as strings. (So timestamps work fine.) The current system works well and according to reports of other users should scale to 10x our current load. It's just expensive.

Comment: @Optimal, please see update 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since ACID isn't needed and you're okay with tasks potentially running twice, I wouldn't keep the timestamps in the database at all.  For each task, create a list of [timestamp_of_next_run, task_id] and use a [min-heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) to store all of the lists.  Python's [heapq](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html) module can maintain the heap for you.  You'll be able to very efficiently pop off the task with the soonest timestamp.  When you need to run a task, use its task_id to look up in the database what the task needs to do.  When a task completes, update the timestamp and put it back into the heap.  (Just be careful not to change an item that's currently in the heap, as that will break the heap properties).

Use the database only to store information that you will still care about after a crash and reboot.  If you won't need the information after a reboot, don't spend the time writing to disk.  You will still have a lot of database read operations to load the information about a task that needs to run, but a read is much cheaper than a write.

If you don't have enough RAM to store all of the tasks in memory at the same time, you could go with a hybrid setup where you keep the tasks for the next 24 hours (for example) in RAM and everything else stays in the database.  Alternately, you could rewrite the code in C or C++, which are less memory hungry.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks! After consultation with a variety of people in the know we're going with a solution that uses heapq.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want a database, you could store just the next run timestamp and task id in memory. You could store the properties for each task in a file named [task_id].txt. You would need a data structure to store all the tasks, sorted by timestamp in memory, an AVL tree seems like it would work, here's a simple one for python: http://bjourne.blogspot.com/2006/11/avl-tree-in-python.html. Hopefully Linux (I assume that's what you are running on) could handle millions of files in a directory, otherwise you might need to hash on the task id to get a sub folder).

Your master server would just need to run a loop, popping off tasks out of the AVL tree until the next task's timestamp is in the future. Then you could sleep for a few seconds and start checking again. Whenever a task runs, you would update the next run timestamp in the task file and re-insert it into the AVL tree.

When the master server reboots, there would be the overhead of reloading all tasks id and next run timestamp back into memory, so that might be painful with millions of files. Maybe you just have one giant file and give each task 1K space in the file for properties and next run timestamp and then use [task_id] * 1K to get to the right offset for the task properties.

If you are willing to use a database, I am confident MySQL could handle whatever you throw at it given the conditions you describe, assuming you have 4GB+ RAM and several hard drives in RAID 0+1 on your master server.

Finally, if you really want to get complicated, Hadoop might work too: http://hadoop.apache.org/

Comment: Jeff, appreciate your response. We're at about 200 writes per second now and are planning for 10x the number of jobs. It may be that a database solution is the the only way to go, but I am (perhaps vainly) looking for an approach that doesn't require constant indexing of timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about writes, you can have a set of servers that dispatch the tasks (may be stripe the servers to equalize load) and have each server write bulk checkpoints to the DB (this way, you will not have so many write queries). You still have to write to be able to recover if scheduling server dies, of course.

In addition, if you don't have a clustered index on timestamp, you will avoid having a hot-spot at the end of the table.

Answer (score 1):

> 350,000 tasks * 48 times per day is
>   16,800,000 tasks executed per day.

To schedule the jobs, you don't need a database.

Databases are for things that are **updated**.  The only update visible here is a change to the schedule to add, remove or reschedule a job.

Cron does this in a totally scalable fashion with a single flat file.

Read the entire flat file into memory, start spawning jobs.  Periodically, check the fstat to see if the file changed.  Or, even better, wait for a HUP signal and use that to reread the file.  Use `kill -HUP` to signal the scheduler to reread the file.

It's unclear what you're **updating** the database for.

If the database is used to determine future schedule based on job completion, then a single database is a Very Dad Idea.

If you're using the database to do some analysis of job history, then you have a simple data warehouse.

1. Record completion information (start time, end time, exit status, all that stuff) in a simple flat log file.
2. Process the flat log files to create a fact table and dimension updates.

When someone has the urge to do some analysis, load relevant portions of the flat log files into a datamart so they can do queries and counts and averages and the like.

Do not directly record 17,000,000 rows per day into a relational database.  No one wants all that data.  They want summaries: counts and averages.

Comment: We're using the database to schedule jobs, and I agree that it's a bad idea. It is resource intensive and cost prohibitive. The question is how we should schedule jobs, not what we should use the database for.

Comment: @wehriam: The question focuses on the update intensity.  Since the question mentioned "substantial write load", it appeared to be important.  Are you saying "substantial write load" is not important?   Querying a database is no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why hundreds of thousands and not hundreds of millions ? :evil:

I think you need stackless python, http://www.stackless.com/. created by the genius of Christian Tismer.

Quoting

> Stackless Python is an enhanced
>   version of the Python programming
>   language. It allows programmers to
>   reap the benefits of thread-based
>   programming without the performance
>   and complexity problems associated
>   with conventional threads. The
>   **microthreads** that Stackless adds to
>   Python are a cheap and lightweight
>   convenience which can if used
>   properly, give the following benefits:
>   Improved program structure. More
>   readable code. Increased programmer
>   productivity.

Is used for massive multiplayer games.

Comment: Hey what is this, I am serious, forget about all that machinery of hadoop and stuff like that and try stackless. You don't even need a database.